# Multiple boot options on startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-vista, dell-inspiron

I bought a new Dell Inspiron with Windows 8 installed. I was able to get Windows 7 installed and all the drivers loaded just fine. When it came time to transfer data from my old hard drive, I removed it from my old laptop and plugged it into my new computer to pull the data off.

It just so happened that when I rebooted it recognized the external hard drive and tried a recovery of the old OS. Now every time I reboot the computer it prompts to boot into Windows 7 or the Windows Vista recovery OS. The hard drive is no longer plugged into the computer and I still receive this prompt on startup. I need to figure out how to get the computer to stop recognizing the old Vista recovery so that I am no longer prompted.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix the prompts. It happens to be through the msconfig.

[My computer asks me to choose which OS I want when I boot](https://superuser.com/questions/657215/my-computer-asks-me-to-choose-which-os-i-want-when-i-boot)

Thanks Super User.